# Looking for a slick way to get from a hash of array to INSERT

Tags: sql, arrays, ruby, hash

I have some routines that scrape data into a hash of equally sized arrays, each of which eventually corresponds to a database column with a name corresponding to the key.

```
test_hash = {
  a: [1,2,3],
  b: [4,5,6],
  c: [7,8,9]
}
```

I need to INSERT into a SQLITE3 DB so I need to iterate the following (3 times in this case)

```
INSERT INTO the_table ['a', 'b', 'c'] VALUES [1, 4, 7]
```

I can get the keys simply with

```
test_hash.keys
```

but I can't get an index to be visible inside the block to get at the values

```
3.times do |n|
  test_hash.collect { |x| x.last[n] }
end
```

I noticed that the hash entry gets mapped to an array of two elements when pushed into the block as x. First element is the key of the hash and the second the array, thus the .last. For the record, if I substitute 0,1, or 2 for n in the block I get the appropriately format row I'm seeking.

I can see several data table like applications to being able to do this, also. What's the approach here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`Array#transpose`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose) with the transform the input and then just iterate over it:

```
test_hash = {
  a: [1,2,3],
  b: [4,5,6],
  c: [7,8,9]
}

attributes = test_hash.values.transpose
#=> [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]

attributes.each do |attrs|
  # method to build the SQL insert statement with `attrs` as arguments
end
```

Comment: Simple! Thanks, @spickermann. I didn't think about the transpose method since I had hash on the brain.